# Are Windows Updates susceptible to tampering, eg. using a MiTM attack.

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, updates

My real question is how are patches and updates authenticated in general. But for example how does windows know a windows update is really a windows update, does it just trust the URL or is there some kind of certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All updates are digitally signed by Microsoft's private key, you will get warnings if any updates are not signed, or signed with the wrong key. Even if a MiTM was able to send fake updates they'd be rejected by the update utility for that reason.

Comment: Unless somebody gets hold of Microsoft's private key.  Do you know how MS would deal with that situation?

Answer (score 3):

Comodohacker, the guy who breached DigiNotar last year, claimed that he is able to issue fake certificates in the identity of Microsoft, and that he could provide fake updates.
http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-20104883-83/comodohacker-i-can-issue-fake-windows-updates/
I haven't heard any confirmation of this happening, and Microsoft moved immediately to revoke the trust of DigiNotar as soon as the hack was announced, so it's possible nothing happened as a result.

But my advice is you are still much safer trusting it than you are to run un-patched; just don't be completely surprised if someone does breach it some day.